# What does this line mean?

Tags: meaning

哦，您原来跟齐天大圣一个姓埃我爸差点晕倒。。
I found this on http://m.zol.com.cn/xiaohua/detail45/44743.html.

Comment: With proper punctuation and line separation, it should be "哦，您原来跟齐天大圣一个姓! // 唉.... 我爸差点晕倒。 "

Answer (score 1):

我爸是个医生。有一次，我爸给一个病人看玻那个病人问:请问您尊姓大名？我爸说:姓齐。那个病人说：哦，您原来跟齐天大圣一个姓埃我爸差点晕倒。

The real name of 齐天大圣 is 孙悟空 (one of the major characters in [西游记](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_West)) so its family name is 孙, but the patient misinterpreted, he think his family name is齐.

Maybe I could translate it in EN:

> My father is a doctor. Once he met a patient.
>
> The patient: "What's your name, sir?"(very formal/serious tone)
>
> My father: "My family name is 齐(qi)" (We won't call one's first name
>   if we're not familiar to him in general for regard)
>
> The patient: "Wow, your family name is the same as
>   齐(qi)天(tian)大(da)圣(sheng)'s!"(surprised tone)
>
> My father nearly passed out at that time.

Comment: No, the patient mistook 齊天大聖's surname as "齊".  It should be "孫" instead.

Comment: @HenryHO So what's the difference between my answer and yours?

Comment: @Liong You said the patient mistook the doctor's surname as 齊.  But it's the other way round: He mistook 齊天大聖's surname as "齊".

Comment: @HenryHO Well, my fault.

Comment: @Liong .... or is it me misinterpreting your words?  It's very likely indeed .....

Comment: @HenryHO You're right. Although 孙悟空 seems human being but it's a monkey actually, I typed without thinking much. Anyway, it will let one misinterpret and it should be corrected. thx~ :-D

Comment: It's not "he" or "it".  I thought the word "misinterpreted" refers to something more recent, which is his conversation with the doctor.  :)

Comment: @HenryHO Well, maybe I should use "齐天大圣's". Is that better?

Comment: Or "The patient thought the family name of 齐天大圣 (one of the major characters in 西游记) was 齐.  Indeed, it is well-known that his real name is 孙悟空 and his family name is 孙."

Comment: @HenryHO Nice! I'll correct it when I am able to use my PC as the Android client was not good enough... Or you can help me and you may get a medal BTW. LOL...